# How can I get the image picker on the WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: redactor, image, richtext

I am running on the latest version of Craft (Craft CMS 2.6.3015).  I have a blog entry, which has a Rich Text editor for the body field.

However, I do not have an image or file upload field in the WYSIWYG editor, please see the screenshot below.

[image]

I have tried adding "image" to the array in `/craft/config/redactor/Standard.json` but it has no effect.

I have checked the storage folder and all folders have correct permissions.

Where is the button and how can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create an asset source in order to use the image upload functionality.  Once an asset source was created the button displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to change your Redactor Config to `Default` in the rich text field settings. Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is already set to Default.  I've tried changing to something else and changing back to no avail.